# Time dependent resistance using SimScape Electrical foundation library in Matlab

Tags: matlab, simscape

I'm trying to model a large electrical network of resistors and capacitors in SimScape using Electrical foundation library blocks. One of the resistors needs to change its resistance as a function of time, say like this:

```
R=R0*(1-delR*(1-exp(-t))
```

where R is resistance, R0 is the initial resistance, delR is the factor by which I want the resistance to decrease and t is time. I can't figure out how to incorporate time variance at all in to the simscape model(as I can't seem to access a time variable). There is a variable resistance block available, but I'm facing the same problem there as well, as it seems to be built to vary with respect to voltage. I'm using Matlab 2016a.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- Use the variable resistance block in conjunction with the clock block to achieve this.
- Build your own block (a good starting point is the source code for variable resistance). And use the time keyword:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/lang/time.html

Your equations could look something like:

let 
R = R0 * (1 - delR * (1 - exp(time));
in 
v == R * i;